# Prove that the language is context free

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-language, pushdown-automaton

How can we design a PDA for the language

```
L= {w | number of 010s in w is more than the number of 101s}
```

to prove it is context free

Comment: Are you trying to prove that it's strictly context-free (as in definitely not regular)? If so, create a PDA for this language, and use the pumping lemma for regular languages to show that the language is not regular. If not, just create the PDA, which will show that the language is at most context-free.

Comment: thanks, but i wanted to get an idea on how to design a pda for this.

Answer (score 0):

You use the stack as a counter for the difference of the numbers of 010 and 101 up to the point you have read. For example, you can use A to count the 010 if they have been more and B for the 101.

Now in your state you remember the last two symbols you have seen. If together with the currently read symbol they form 010 you:

- Put an A on the stack if the topmost stack symbol is an A or the stack is empty.
- Else remove a B from the stack.

Analogously for 101.

So when you finish reading the input there is one ore more A on the stack if the input word is to be accepted.